# wxPython grid function suddenly stops being *callable* after the first pass to wx.CallAfter

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I use: `import wx.grid as gridlib` and then I do this inside the class that inherits `wx.Panel`:

```
self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
self.grid.CreateGrid(10000, 17)
```

And it creates a large grid. Now when I do this in a function that is being called by another thread:

```
current_line  = 1
wx.CallAfter(self.grid.SetCellValue(current_line - 1, 1, "SMTH"))
current_line += 1
wx.CallAfter(self.grid.SetCellValue(current_line - 1, 1, "SMTH"))
```

On the second `wx.CallAfter` I get:

> assert callable(callableObj), "callableObj is not callable"
>   AssertionError: callableObj is not callable

So it means the object loses its method? I mean functions in python are objects, so the `SetCellValue` object is somehow deleted?

Comment: Could you be so kind and accept answers (or disagree with the solutions) for your other questions before starting another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not doing what you think it is doing. `wx.CallAfter` is basically called by having several arguments. The first argument is a **reference** to the function/method `CallAfter` should call, the following arguments are the arguments which shall be passed on to the function/method reference in the first argument (see `wx._core`):

```
def CallAfter(callableObj, *args, **kw):
```

You pointed already to the complete source of `wx.CallAfter` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615002/wxpython-wx-callafter-how-do-i-get-it-to-execute-immediately) post.

What you are doing instead is **calling** the method/function yourself and passing the *result* to `CallAfter`. Therefore the first call seems to work, because calling happens first and `CallAfter` fails later on (because it gets the result of `….SetCellValue(…)` instead a reference.

So you should simply write instead for both lines:

```
wx.CallAfter(self.grid.SetCellValue, current_line - 1, 1, "SMTH")
```